# Encrypt a small string with RSA in javascript then decrypt in java on server

Tags: java, javascript, encryption, rsa, jsbn

I want to encrypt a small string in javascript using RSA with public keys and then decrypt that string in java server side code using private keys.

I am using this code in javascript:
http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/
Example at:
http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/rsa2.html

and this code on java side:
[Encrypting string in javascript and decryption in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737390/encrypting-string-in-javascript-and-decryption-in-java)

Both of codes work good independently but they do not understand each other. Need to solve this today or I am open to accept any other asymmetrical algorithm that works this way.

Comment: "they do not understand each other" - can you follow both algorithms through and work out why they diverge? Is it simply that they encode the result differently, or one assumes a fixed exponent, or one can't cope with the size of modulous in the other one, or something else?

Comment: Note that just grabbing any data from the internet has seldom led to secure systems. YOu should not just trust any code and use popular, well researched libraries.

Answer (score 4):

You are using raw encryption on the Java side and RSA encryption using PKCS#1 v1.5 padding on the Java Card side. You should try and use Java RSA through the `javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/PKCS1Padding")`. Don't forget to remove any base 64 encoding if that is present.

Answer (score 4):

wanna leave the example for further generations :)

First, we need to generate key pair in java code

```java
KeyPairGenerator kpg;
    try {
        kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
        yourVariablePublic = kp.getPublic();
        yourVariablePublic = kp.getPrivate();
    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

Now let`s move to java code of our current page:

```java
// receiving public key from where you store it
    Key publicKey = YourCarrierClass.getYourVariablePublic();
    KeyFactory fact;
    // initializing public key variable
    RSAPublicKeySpec pub = new RSAPublicKeySpec(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ZERO);
    try {
        fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        pub = fact.getKeySpec(publicKey,    RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
    } catch(InvalidKeySpecException e) {
    }

// now you should pass Modulus string onto your html(jsp) in such way
String htmlUsedModulus = pub.getModulus().toString(16);
// send somehow this String to page, so javascript can use it
```

Now for javascript side:

```
function sendPassword() {
    var password = $('#passwordField').val();
    var rsa = new RSAKey();
    rsa.setPublic($('#keyModulus').text(), '10001');
    var res = rsa.encrypt(password);
    $('#ajaxSentPassword').val(res);
}
```

And to decrypt it in java code:

```java
 Key privateKey = YourCarrierClass.getYourVariablePrivate();
 Cipher cipher;
 BigInteger passwordInt = new BigInteger(ajaxSentPassword, 16);
 byte[] dectyptedText = new byte[1];
 try {
   cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
   byte[] passwordBytes = passwordInt.toByteArray();
   cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
   dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(passwordBytes);
   } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
   } catch(NoSuchPaddingException e) { 
   } catch(InvalidKeyException e) {
   } catch(IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
   } catch(BadPaddingException e) {
   }
   String passwordNew = new String(dectyptedText);
   System.out.println("Password new " + passwordNew);
```

Here you go, sorry, I`m not good in handling these catch clauses.

====================================================================

Upd:
Here I found out some issues, regarding this code.
First of all, you can change algorithm of

```
javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

to:

```
javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
```

But this is not essential, it works with both.
Now the real problem is regarding this line

```
byte[] passwordBytes = passwordInt.toByteArray();
```

here when you generate byte array from BigInteger, it sometimes adds [0] in front as signum (Sometimes NOT! so algorithm can decipher that array), so byte array size can be 65/129/257, which cannot be deciphered by algorithm, it throws IllegalBlockSizeException. This problem is discussed in [Getting 1 byte extra in the modulus RSA Key and sometimes for exponents also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515691/getting-1-byte-extra-in-the-modulus-rsa-key-and-sometimes-for-exponents-also) question.
The simplest solution is just throw away that zero from array:

```
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[256];

    BigInteger passwordInt = new BigInteger(password, 16);
    if (passwordInt.toByteArray().length > 256) {
        for (int i=1; i<257; i++) {
            byteArray[i-1] = passwordInt.toByteArray()[i];
        }
    } else {
        byteArray = passwordInt.toByteArray();
    }
```